# How can I specify which Google login to get docs from in Trello?

Tags: google-drive, trello

I am logged into 3 Google accounts. I want to attach a document from Google drive to a Trello card but I can only select a document from the default account. Is there a way to specify in Trello which Google account I want to get the doc from?

Or do I just have to paste the link and use that?

I guess a workaround is to share it with myself but ... meh.

Logging in with the Google account didn't work either.

Comment: So far sharing a folder with my other Google login has been the easiest workaround.

Comment: If you go to http://drive.google.com, you can switch which account you are logged in with.

Comment: That doesn't seem to affect where Trello looks for the list of docs.

Answer (score 1):

Goto https://drive.google.com/ then click on setting gear and then settings. Click Manage apps in the popup and then find trello and disable it. Now goto trello and choose the Google account that you want.